# Clear AppStore cookies and locally stored data

Tags: mac-appstore

How to clear my OSX 10.8 AppStore cookies and locally stored data?

I also heard that there's a debug mode in AppStore, How can I enable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable the Debug menu by typing the following into Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
```

You can then clear the cookies using the Clear Cookies option in the Debug menu.

In addition, you can reset the application using the Reset Application option.

[image: App Store Debug Menu]

You can disable the Debug menu using the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool false
```

Comment: [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fww7exxi9lsc7ey/44.jpeg?v=1rc-) is what I see when you guys with retina Macs post pictures here... :)